# htaccess redirect primary domain http to https w/out redirect of domains on shared host

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have searched the site and thought I may have found code I could use for my issue, but it did not work.

I want to redirect my primary domain http to https (also including any form of url typed www. without www., http://www, http://, and even just the domain name without www or http before it), while Also not effecting my other domain that is sharing the same hosting within my primary directory (as the SSL I have only used for primary domain, but not used on other domains).

At current, I had code to make the redirect for my primary to https, but it would then make my other domain on same hosting account, also redirect to https. 
Then I found code to not effect the other domain and not to redirect to https, but then it effected my primary domain to NOT redirect to https either, it would only redirect to https if with www. or http but would not redirect without the www.

This has been very frustrating because I am VERY new to attempting this type of code, so I don't have a clue what I am doing and could surely use the help. My Godaddy hosting would not help but give link to basic redirect code which does not help for other domains sharing hosting, nor did it work for typing domain without www etc. I hope this made sense.

Thank you in advance.

EDITED possible FIX:
Ok, my code might look a bit wonky and I'm sure it may need cleaning up and possible repetitive stuff removed, but this is what I just patched together from other code offerings I've found on this site, along with others I've found elsewhere and I think it might be working. I'm sure there is a cleaner way to format this, but at current it seems to be working.

```
# redirect http to https Domain   
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.yoursite.com [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} yoursite.com
RewriteRule (.*)  https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yoursite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# redirect to http subdomain 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www).+\.yoursite\.com)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I would advise choosing a canonical name for your domain to redirect to rather than just trying to force https.  Is there a reason you are trying to use https?

Comment: @AdamCarr I am using https because I am a business that needs to be secure with an SSL Cert. for security and assurance for customers purchasing my art and passing their info through my webshop.